# How to remove linux from a dual boot (Mint/Windows 10) NOT FROM A PARTITION but from 2 different disks?

Tags: windows

Can I do the same as we do if the two systems are in the same HDD in 2 partitions or there is something else I should consider?

Answer (score 1):

delete the partition while in windows, reboot and do a [fixmbr](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/repair-master-boot-record-mbr-windows) afterwards with a windows live CD/flashdrive

Answer (score 0):

For safety, first update the bootloader, and make sure than you can still boot into the windows partition without getting the choice.  Be very sure you know which disk/partition is used by which OS (if you delete the wrong partitions you might never be able to boot into anything).

Then just boot into windows and delete the two Linux partitions (hopefully Microsoft will warn you if you try to delete the wrong one).  That will leave you downgraded to "only windows".  The extra disk doesn't make a difference - it's just like having C: and D: drives in windows.

Of course, you could do it the other way around, and delete the windows partitions ;)